# Hello,I have a file decoder.py that a run in a jupyter notebook with the syntaxe !python decoder.py. How do I get the results in the jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have this .py file: decoder.py
After executing the code, it should display some plots. I forgot to import matplotlib.
After executing !python decoder.py in my jupyter notebook, it gives an error.

I want to ask if there is a way of using the getting the output of the code without rerunning the entire code, as it take 21 hours.
I means, from the decoder.y, I have these command:
`x = stat_dict['plog']`
`y = stat_dict['cycles']`
`plt.plot(x,y)`
when I typed print(x ) in jupyter notebook, it says x is not defined

Is there a way of getting x and y without rerunning the entire code?
Thanks

Comment: `!python ...` runs the script in the subshell. The variables inside of the script are not in any way in the scope of the outside script (in your case in jupyter notebook). When the script is finished, all the variables are lost.

Comment: I see. Is there a way save those variables? or the better idea is to run the file in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: There's not much info on your exact use case. But in most cases, the best way to use variables from one python script in another python script is to import them (`from decoder import x, y`). But as you say it runs 21 hours, you'd probably be better off serializing them into files and then deserializing them in your notebook. It looks like `stat_dict` is a JSON, so you can just dump it into .json file and load it in you notebook